# Python mediapipe object detection RuntimeError

Tags: python, mediapipe

The goal of this application is to run a program that runs in a cycle where it keeps detecting for human presence and followed by hand landmark detection. The image below is the flowchart of the application.

[image]

my main.py code look like the following:

```
def main():
    while True:
        detect_person()
        hand_gesture()
```

*detect_person* function will halt once it detects a person for a period of time frame which allows the next process to begin

```
def detect_person():
    model_path = "efficientdet.tflite"
    if not os.path.exists(model_path):
        print("model does not exist...")
        url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/mediapipe-models/object_detector/efficientdet_lite0/int8/1/efficientdet_lite0.tflite"
        download_file(url, model_path)
    else:
        print("model exists...")

    cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
    if not cap.isOpened():
        print("Cannot open camera")
        exit()

    time_count = 1
    while True:
        # Capture frame-by-frame openCV
        _, frame = cap.read()
        frame, has_humans = detect_humans(frame, model_path)

        if has_humans:
            print(time_count)
            if time_count % 10 == 0:
                temp_file = "image.jpg"
                cv.imwrite(temp_file, frame)
                print("image saved")
                cv.destroyWindow("frame1")
                break
        else:
            time_count = 0
        
        if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break

        time_count += 1
        cv.imshow('frame1', frame)
```

*hand_gesture* function will be halted when user's press 'q' key on the keyboard

```
def detect_hand():
    mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands
    hands = mp_hands.Hands()
    mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
    
    cap = cv.VideoCapture(0) 

    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            continue

        frame = cv.flip(frame, 1)
        rgb_frame = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        results = hands.process(rgb_frame)

        if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for landmarks in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(frame, landmarks, mp_hands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)

        cv.imshow('Hand Landmarks Detection', frame)

        if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

What should happen next is the person detection, continuing the cycle. However, this is the error message I receive after quitting the hand landmark detection

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\dev\data-science\project\ic2-robot\google-tts\Michael-Pollution\run.py", line 139, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\dev\data-science\project\ic2-robot\google-tts\Michael-Pollution\run.py", line 136, in main
    run()
  File "D:\dev\data-science\project\ic2-robot\google-tts\Michael-Pollution\run.py", line 132, in run
    detect_person()
  File "D:\dev\data-science\project\ic2-robot\google-tts\Michael-Pollution\run.py", line 35, in detect_person
    frame, has_humans = detect_humans(frame, model_path)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\dev\data-science\project\ic2-robot\google-tts\Michael-Pollution\humanDetection\HumanDetection.py", line 46, in detect_humans
    detector = vision.ObjectDetector.create_from_options(options)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\dev\data-science\project\ic2-robot\google-tts\Lib\site-packages\mediapipe\tasks\python\vision\object_detector.py", line 234, in create_from_options
    return cls(
           ^^^^
  File "D:\dev\data-science\project\ic2-robot\google-tts\Lib\site-packages\mediapipe\tasks\python\vision\core\base_vision_task_api.py", line 70, in __init__
    self._runner = _TaskRunner.create(graph_config, packet_callback)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: Unable to open file at D:\dev\data-science\project\ic2-robot\google-tts\Lib\site-packages/D:\dev\data-science\project\ic2-robot\google-tts\Michael-Pollution\efficientdet.tflite, errno=22
```

Briefly, it might seems like the error is produced due to invalid path name to the tensorflow lite model for person detection. However, what I found that is that, the part that is causing the error is inside the hand landmark detection function. I tried not applying the hand landmark detection, and just have my camera opened by opencv and the cycle works as expected. So, I'm not so sure what the problem here.